# asynchronous socket server, killing thread c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

Im having some kind of trouble on my asynchronous socket server in c, i though in moving it to java, but first i want to solve this problem.

i have a detached thread for each connection (not client), when its done it closes it, im having a problem when the server gets 2 connections at the same time, it kind of leave the old behind and starts with the new...

this is the code:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
 int server_portno=1111;
 int sockfd, newsockfd,option=1;
 int *new_sock;
 socklen_t clilen;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

 /* First call to socket() function */
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0)
 {
     addLog("ERROR opening socket\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 /* Initialize socket structure */
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_portno);

 /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                      sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
 {
     addLog("ERROR on binding\n");
     exit(1);
 }

 if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&option,sizeof(option)) < 0)
 {
     addLog("setsockopt failed\n");
     close(sockfd);
     exit(2);
 }
/* Now start listening for the clients, here
 * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
 * for the incoming connection
 */
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
while((newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
   (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen)))
{
    addLog("connection accepted\n");
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t tattr;
    new_sock =malloc(sizeof(int));
    *new_sock = newsockfd;
    pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if(pthread_create(&thread,&tattr,doprocessing,new_sock)<0)
    {
        addLog("could not create thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    addLog("Handler assigned\n");
 }
return 0;
}

void addLog(char info[300])
{
    printf("%s",info);
    return;
}
void *doprocessing (void* sock_info)
{
    int *sock=(int*)sock_info;
    int n;
    char buffer[10000],logInfo[200];
    bzero(buffer,10000);
    n = read(*sock,buffer,10000);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        addLog("ERROR reading from socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(logInfo,"Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    addLog(logInfo);
    /*
    * do something
    */
    addLog("Closing port\n");
    close(*sock);
    addLog("freeing port\n");
    free(sock_info);
    addLog("exiting thread\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

this is my client code, i divide it by 4 functions, starts, stop, send and receive:

```
#define CONNECTION_STARTED 1
#define CONNECTION_NOT_STARTED 0
#..all return macros here too..
int sockfd;
int status=CONNECTION_NOT_STARTED;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
int socket_start_connection()
{
    addLog("starting connection\n");
    if(status==CONNECTION_STARTED)
        return SOCKET_SUCCESS_CONNECTION_OPEN;
    char *serverAddr=SERVER_HOSTNAME;//example.ex
    int portno,valopt,res;
    struct hostent *server;
    struct timeval tv;
    socklen_t lon;
    fd_set myset;
    long arg;


    sockfd=-1;
    portno =SERVER_PORT;//1111
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        addLog("ERROR opening socket");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_OPENING_PORT;
    }
        server=gethostbyname(serverAddr);
    if (server == NULL) 
    {
       addLog("ERROR no such host");
       return SOCKET_ERROR_HOST_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
        (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if( (arg = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) 
    { 
        addLog("Error fcntl , F_GETFL");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_TIMEOUT_F_GETFL;
    } 
    arg |= O_NONBLOCK; 
    if( fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) 
    { 
        addLog("Error fcntl, F_SETFL");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_TIMEOUT_F_SETFL;
    } 
    res=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    if(res<0)
    {  
        if(errno==EINPROGRESS)
        {
            do
            {
                tv.tv_sec = SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIME_LIMIT;//something like 60 seconds 
                tv.tv_usec = 0; 
                FD_ZERO(&myset); 
                FD_SET(sockfd, &myset); 
                res = select(sockfd+1, NULL, &myset, NULL, &tv); 
                if (res < 0 && errno != EINTR) 
                { 
                    addLog("Error Connecting to server");
                    exit(SOCKET_ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_HOST); 
                }   
                else if (res > 0) 
                { 
                    lon = sizeof(int); 
                    if (getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &lon) < 0) 
                    { 
                        addLog("Error  getsockopt");
                        return SOCKET_ERROR_GETSOCKOPT;
                    } 
              // Check the value returned... 
                    if (valopt) 
                    { 
                        addLog("Error in connection to server");
                        socket_stop_connection();
                        return SOCKET_ERROR_DELAYED_CONNECTION;
                    } 
                    break; 
                }               
                else
                {
                    addLog("Error, time limited exceed");
                    socket_stop_connection();
                    return SOCKET_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
                }
            }while(1);
        }
    }
     // Set to blocking mode again... 
    if( (arg = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) 
    { 
        addLog("Error fcntl , F_GETFL");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_TIMEOUT_F_GETFL;
    } 
    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK); 
    if( fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) 
    { 
        addLog("Error fcntl , F_SETFL");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_TIMEOUT_F_SETFL;
    }
    status=CONNECTION_STARTED;
    return SOCKET_SUCCESS_CONNECTION_OPEN;
}
int socket_stop_connection()
{
    addLog("stopping connection\n");    
    if(status==CONNECTION_NOT_STARTED)
        return SOCKET_ERROR_CLOSING_CONNECTION;
    close(sockfd);
    status=CONNECTION_NOT_STARTED;
    return SOCKET_SUCCESS_CONNECTION_CLOSED;
}
int socket_send_message(char* message)
{
    addLog("sending message\n");
    if(!status==CONNECTION_STARTED)
    {
        socket_start_connection();
        if(!status==CONNECTION_STARTED)
            {
                addLog("ERROR NOT CONNECTED");
                return SOCKET_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED;
            }
    }
    int n; 
    n = write(sockfd,message,strlen(message));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        addLog("ERROR writing to socket");
        return SOCKET_ERROR_WRITING_TO_SOCKET;
    }
    return SOCKET_SUCCESS_MESSAGE_SENT;
}
int socket_receive_message(char* buffer)
{
    addLog("receiving message\n");
    if(!status==CONNECTION_STARTED)
    {
        addLog("ERROR NOT CONNECTED");
    return SOCKET_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
    int n;
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
         addLog("ERROR reading from socket");
    close(sockfd);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    return SOCKET_SUCCESS_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
}
```

Comment: @Dmitri so how you think i should manage it? with an array?

Comment: It shouldn't matter since they're detached threads and you don't need to save the `pthread_t`, etc... when I noticed that I deleted my comment.

Comment: Meh, bzero cargo-cult:(   Apart from that, I can't see any of the usual suspects re. two clients 'interfering' with each other.  You correctly malloc up a socket and pass the pointer to the client<>server thread.  You even remember to free it at the end.  Note that the bzero, or the saner use of 'n' to put a nul on the end of the data in the buffer, would fail if either binary data with nulls is being exchanged, or if the buffer was comletely filled with data by the recv() call.  If your buffer is 10000, you should read 9999 and use 'n' to place a null at the end.

Comment: And do note you could end up trying to shove 10K worth of data into a 200 byte log message with your unchecked `sprintf(logInfo,"Here is the message: %s\n",buffer)`. Buffer termination is important as Martin described and both of these should be fixed. Also, `clilen` should be reset to `sizeof cli_addr` at the tail of the while-loop, but that's more a formality than anything else.

Comment: i dont know if i should add that in the "do something" i return a value to the client and usually it dies there... when it should return to the client some value and a new connection starts , it leaves the old unanswered :(

Comment: OK , it seems like we need to see the 'do something':)

Comment: im going to add first the client, there might be some error somewhere there (upload the do something its really complicated and is in spanish :P) @MartinJames

Comment: If there is any doubt as to which peer is causing issues, you should cut the problem in half with wireshark.

Comment: im going to read about it and use it for testing, thanks @MartinJames